# Migrate Cordova to Crosswalk - Fails on API v14

Tags: android, cordova, ant, crosswalk-runtime

I am following the **Migrate using command line tools** steps from this page: https://crosswalk-project.org/#documentation/cordova/migrate_an_application

When I get to step 6 and run **ant debug** it returns a lot of errors:

```
-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] No changes in the AndroidManifest files.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [aapt] /Users/jacquesblom/Repo/testics/platforms/android/CordovaLib/xwalk_core_library/res/layout/color_picker_advanced_component.xml:11: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_marginStart' in package 'android'
     [aapt] /Users/jacquesblom/Repo/testics/platforms/android/CordovaLib/xwalk_core_library/res/layout/color_picker_advanced_component.xml:11: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_marginEnd' in package 'android'
     [aapt] /Users/jacquesblom/Repo/testics/platforms/android/CordovaLib/xwalk_core_library/res/layout/color_picker_advanced_component.xml:20: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_marginStart' in package 'android'
     [aapt] /Users/jacquesblom/Repo/testics/platforms/android/CordovaLib/xwalk_core_library/res/layout/color_picker_advanced_component.xml:20: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_marginEnd' in package 'android'
     [aapt] /Users/jacquesblom/Repo/testics/platforms/android/CordovaLib/xwalk_core_library/res/layout-v17/color_picker_advanced_component.xml:11: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_marginStart' in package 'android'
     **… several more of these**

BUILD FAILED
/Users/jacquesblom/android-sdk/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:601: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/jacquesblom/android-sdk/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:653: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/jacquesblom/android-sdk/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:698: null returned: 1
```

This occurs when I set the Android SDK version to 14 (**android update project --subprojects --path . --target "android-14"**), but the problem disappears when I bump it up to version 19.

What could be the issue here?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you get this sorted? I'm having the same issue...

Comment: In fact, I've got it working. I *think* it was because there was a space in the path to the sdk - `/Applications/Android SDK`. I did try a few things, but after that point it seemed to work.